# electrum server install ImportError

Tags: leveldb

I have a trouble when i installed the electrum server.The electrum server install document reference(https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum-server/blob/master/HOWTO.md).everything has been done before run "electrum-server start" command to launch electrum server.but it print an error: "ImportError: /home/bitcoin/.python-eggs/plyvel-0.9-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg-tmp/plyvel/_plyvel.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6snappy13RawUncompressEPKcmP".

I have google with the keyword "_ZN6snappy13RawUncompressEPKcmP". i found a reference in this page("https://github.com/wbolster/plyvel/issues/5"). I do as this page said, but finally failed.
  my leveldb is 1.9, i install the liblevedb1,libleveldb-dev,plyvel.
  can anybody help me with this big problem.thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need both LevelDB and Snappy libraries installed, including their development headers.